# Why did the permissions of my mongodb .sock file change automatically?

Tags: linux, mongodb, amazon-web-services, file-permissions

Today, my MongoDB database went down after weeks of it being up. After some digging around, I realized that the permissions of my `mongodb-27017.sock` file were incorrect.

Running `chown mongod:mongod mongodb-27017.sock` resolved the issue.

My MongoDB instance was running perfectly fine for *weeks*. How did the permissions all of a suddenly change? How can I prevent myself from running into this issue again?

For context: I'm running an Amazon Linux 2 instance on AWS.

Answer (score 2):

After almost one year of flawless working, one of our replica members received an error and it was related to this, mongo.sock owner changed from **mongod:mongod** to **root:root**.

I started searching that if I can find what changed the files owner but unfortunately there's no way to find it after it happened.
So my search lead me to ***auditctl***.

According to man page the description is, `used to control the behavior, get status, and add or delete rules.`

By setting up it like `audictl -w /tmp -p rwxa -k keyname`, I started waiting.

Wrote a simple shell script to notify me when audictl finds out what's changing the ownership of the file. After couple hours, I received it.
With the output of the audictl, you can find information like ***pid***, ***syscall*** and ***uid*** etc.

But the most important one is ***comm*** which tells you which program used and caused this change.

For my situation by following the audictl logs, I found out that co-worker of mine just created a cronjob that effects mongo.sock file.